# Subnet entries in the routing table

Tags: linux, routes, subnet

I am looking into a routing table issue that is a bit perplexing. Consider the routing table below. I am curious how the subnet entries get added to this table. Primarily the destinations 10.200.232.0/23 and 169.254.0.0/16. What triggers these entries to be added to the routing table? My gut tells me that if I configure an address/alias on the eth0 interface that it will add the routing table entry for the corresponding subnet.

```
Destination        Gateway           Flags      Refs    Use   Life Intf
0.0.0.0            10.200.232.1      UGC           0      0      - eth0
10.100.0.6         10.200.232.1      UGHc          1      2    300 eth0
10.200.1.6         10.200.232.1      UGH3c         0      1   3599 eth0
**10.200.232.0/23    unresolved        UC            0      0      - eth0**
10.200.232.1       XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX UHLc          3      0    300 eth0
10.200.232.139     XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX UHLc          3      2   1200 eth0
**169.254.0.0/16     unresolved        UC            0      0      - eth0**
127.0.0.0/8        127.0.0.1         UG            0      0    298 lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1         UH            1      0    297 lo0
224.0.0.0/7        unresolved        UCt           0      0      - eth0
255.255.255.255    10.200.232.92     UHSb          1      2      - eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use `route` from net-tools (this is obsolete and shows signs of being broken as well in multiple places), but `ip route` from iproute/iproute2. It also tells you what caused the addition of the route in the XXX of the `proto XXX` field.

Comment: I do not have those utilities. The system is actually ECOS so there is no command line environment etc. What I am really looking for hear is a technical explanation of what triggers these subnet entries to get added to the routing table in the general sense of how routing is typically implemented.

Comment: So it looks like interface initialization is what causes these entries to be added. Or adding an ip alias on an existing interface, etc.

Comment: Yes, addition of an interface address with netmask can add a route entry (`proto kernel`). But not in all cases (e.g. lo interface). So to be really sure, using the tool would be non-negotiable.